# Write content to blank tab then submit a form in that blank tab

Tags: javascript, browser, tabs

This is a little difficult to explain but I'll do my best.

My web page displays a report of "things" and next to each thing is an icon which when clicked, opens a new tab which takes the user to a 3rd party site and shows them analytics about that particular thing.

On the icon click, my javascript does an ajax call to my soap service to construct this url (requires my back end to perform a cross domain ajax call). It takes between 20-40 seconds to return (nothing I can do about that).

What I'd like to do is immediately upon clicking the icon, have javascript open a new tab (must be a new tab and not a new window). In that new tab I would like to display a simple message telling the user that they will soon be redirected. Then the ajax call is sent and upon success, the tab is redirected to that url.

The code I have written does everything I need except display a message to the user when it's opened. Can someone tell me how I can write content to this blank tab? Or do I need to create my own page with the message on it and post that instead of about:blank?

Here's what my code looks like:

```
var form = document.forms['form'];
form = document.createElement('form');
form.setAttribute('name', 'form');
form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
form.setAttribute('target', _blank);
form.setAttribute('id', 'uniqueID');
form.setAttribute('action', 'about:blank');

document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();

$.ajax({
  // call to my soap service that returns an URL, this part all works correctly
  // only the success handler is worth showing
  success: function(resultObj) {
    form.setAttribute('action', resultObj.URL);
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: What i would do is create a redirect page that gets any info needed to build your URL from the form. Open this page in the new tab. If by chance your service to build URL and your current web page are on the same server, you probably won't need to do an ajax call anymore.. just redirect with the server language.

Comment: Your requirement `(must be a new tab and not a new window)` is not possible. You **can't** control that, as it is a user preference set in the browser and controlled by the user....

Comment: ...what you can do though, is to create your own "tabbed" solution, where each tab use an `iframe` to show the external result.

Comment: _“Can someone tell me how I can write content to this blank tab?”_ - you can’t, because you got no reference to it to begin with. It is not opened by your script, but automatically due to the form being submitted. _“Or do I need to create my own page with the message on it and post that instead of about:blank?”_ - yes, unless you are willing to use window.open to open the new window instance first. (As @LGSon mentioned, whether that gets you a tab or a “popup”, is pretty much out of your jurisdiction to begin with.)

Comment: Thanks all. I was under the wrong impression that the form append and submit was resulting in the new tab (instead of a new window). Now that I see it's out of my control it definitely makes sense to use window.open as it returns a pointer to the window and the means to write to it.